# WireMock: 200 Stub works but stubs with Service Fault are not found

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-cloud, wiremock

I am using Spring Cloud Contract WireMock to mock my backend calls.What's weird is when i make call with 200 status calls and json file that have success body file, works fine .But when i try to mock service faults like 400,404,504,505.I get **status=404 and Header does not match** even though request is correct.What I have to add to mock service faults.

Here is are stub json files.

200.json

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/api/v1/customer",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": {
        "equalTo": "application/json"
      },
      "name":
      {
        "equalTo": "johnDoe"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "bodyFileName": "clients/200-customer.json"
  }
}
```

Service Faults:

504.json

```
    {
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/api/v1/customer",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": {
        "equalTo": "application/json"
      },
      "name":
      {
        "equalTo": "johnDoe2"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-02-09 14:29:50",
    "status": 504,
    "message": null,
    "error": "java.net.SocketTimeoutException"
  }
}
```

Logs:

```
                                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
/api/*********************************************         | /api/*****************************
                                                           |
Content-Type: application/json                             | Content-Type: application/json
encryptedName:                                             | encryptedName:                                      <<<<< Header does not match
bKY904momNgB2Mr4lt4s6w8_rT1wJ_T5ioTa0tpfxOjSalMgEYvjFDpDp  | WIj32OI4F9UTNbNPkdZK%2BFvp28KsgVnzLhsrhP%2B%2Bey68%2B6ew2
_6jI3JQfJfTwmkpskMddqGamDreNc3rglzf20vZXVWdD9lvwgxndJaJPW  | lnXBDzP7j84uyEncK273j0P4daVBCL7uxDpYg%3D%3D
XuGuJDzyrMJE6pEYKSufxEl56DFAVxQNDtiDvOqAnAU0j2p2reXnsBDUB  |
q_hjVfNDPNTXQLVReJPnv                                      |
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
","timestamp":"10-04-2021 20:42:41.437"}
{"data":{"type":"ClientResponse","path":"/api/*****************************","httpMethod":"GET","duration":"60","status":404,"body":"\n                                               Request was not matched\n                                               =======================\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n| Closest stub      

                                   |
```

Comment: Can you paste your Wiremock mismatch log entry? It should say what did not match exactly.

Comment: added logs.As I mentioned If I change to it success and return success works fine.But Same request fails if i change to server fault.

Comment: You can see that the reason you have no match is the value of the `encryptedName` header. The other issue you are describing might be a red herring.

Comment: As i told when i send same header with 200 body it works ,if i change response body to 400 or 500 it fails.

Comment: Can you paste the log entry when it matches, it should be logging the whole request and mapping before the match?